# How can i show word file in iframe element in same page?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<iframe src="abc.doc" height="800px" width="600px">
</iframe>
</html>
```

How can i show word file in iframe element in same page ?

Comment: Above code not work proper it download .doc or docx file so can anybody have answer how to display that in browser

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that's not possible in this way

Comment: Unfortunately Word support within browsers is awful.  We eventually ended up buying a component to convert Word to PDF and stream that instead.  Even that isn't perfect, but it's better

Comment: so can you have any another way then help me ...

Comment: If you are trying to frame a local word file, the problem is that for security issues you can't frame file: URLs on modern browsers.

Comment: ok i try everything bt it cant show file in current or same page so i thought to develope own document viewer so how can i do that .??

Answer (score 0):

Yup, 
Upload your doc file and link through Iframe
This will work, as google doc viewer works same way.

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
<object src="abc.doc"><embed src="abc.doc"></embed></object>
```