# How to show word file on iframe using base64 data of word file

Tags: html, angular

i have following base 64 data...

data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,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

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210174/how-can-i-show-word-file-in-iframe-element-in-same-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iframe src set large base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766667/iframe-src-set-large-base64-data)